# INSERT or REPLACE is creating duplicates

Tags: php, sqlite

Whenever I execute an "INSERT OR REPLACE" command to sqlite3, it's actually create duplicate entries instead of overwriting the existing entries.

I created the table in sqlite3 with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b VARCHAR(50), c BOOLEAN, d BOOLEAN, e INTEGER, f TEXT, g TEXT, h INTEGER, i DATETIME);
```

And then I'm executing this:

```
$database = new POD("sqlite:mydatabase.db");
$database->prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mytable (b, c, d, e, f, h, h, i) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
$database->execute('test', 0, 1, -1, 'test', 'test', 12, strtotime('now'));
```

What could I be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: It does say REPLACE and not REPACE, right? And you're missing a parentheses on the execute method call.

Comment: Yes it does say REPLACE and there is a parentheses; i should have copied and pasted ;)

Comment: Since your query does not include the primary key, `a`, how would SQLITE know that this data is not new data?

Comment: How can I replace based on one of the columns?

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify in your `create` statement what set of columns should be `unique' -- for example

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b VARCHAR(50), c BOOLEAN, d BOOLEAN,
                      e INTEGER, f TEXT, g TEXT, h INTEGER, i DATETIME,
                      UNIQUE (b,c));
```

Now

```
sqlite> insert or replace into mytable (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) values    ('foo',1,1,2,'bar','baz',3,'2011-07-19');
sqlite> select * from mytable;
2|foo|1|1|2|bar|baz|3|2011-07-19
sqlite> insert or replace into mytable (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) values ('foo',1,1,2,'bar','baz',4,'2011-07-19');
sqlite> select * from mytable;
3|foo|1|1|2|bar|baz|4|2011-07-19
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. You should specify the PK.

Do an initial `INSERT`, then do an `UPDATE`.